# Unique parent-child relationship data in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, parent-child

In a language learning app, each time a user learns a new sentence(which is a document in itself), I would like to add that as a child of the user, so that for each user you can see the sentences that they have already learned.

This is all fine to do with

```
sentences: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Sentence'
      }]
```

However, I would like to add data about that user's relationship with the child, e.g. firstLearnedOnDate: , totalCorrectAnswers: etc. Is this possible in mongoose? Is there a better solution that I'm missing?

I have tried messing around with putting the mongoose.Schema.ObjectId into another object with the other properties which I want, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

you should read about `ref` and `populate`, check the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) and read this
[article](https://medium.com/@nicknauert/mongooses-model-populate-b844ae6d1ee7), with use populate you can do what you want